# Selenium DoubleClick method not getting executed on Infragistics Grid in IE and Firefox

Tags: c#, selenium, infragistics

My application includes an infragistics grid, that when a row/cell is double clicked, a dialog opens.

Using Selenium's Action class with DoubleClick works perfectly fine in Chrome and the dialog opens every time. In IE, the grid row/cell gets highlighted like it was clicked only once and the dialog does not open. In Firefox, the double click gets works about 90% of the time and the dialog opens, but sometimes it performs exactly how it does in IE, where it seems only the row got highlighted (clicked once), not double clicked.

I have tried instead to use two separate Click. This reduced the frequency of the Firefox failures to maybe 3%, but the grid still does not get double clicked in IE regardless of what I try

Original code:

```
                 Actions action = new Actions(Browser);
                 action.DoubleClick(cellElement).Build().Perform();
```

Workaround:

```
                 cellElement.Click();
                 cellElement.Click();
```

Comment: thinking about this, I remembered one of my older projects in which i had to click the element once with a regular click action before actually double clicking it. Don't know if this will work for you of course, but you never know.

Comment: I tried including a click first, then a double click. It seemed to reduce the frequency of failure in FF, but not totally rid the problem. IE fails every time no matter what work-around I have tried

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is an issue with the WebDrivers themselves for IE and Firefox, and not with the way the `igGrid` handles the double click event. We're experiencing the same issue internally with our tests and we've resorted to similar workarounds.

Comment: Are there any workarounds that have worked in IE? For Firefox, I was thinking of including an If statement, where if the row stays highlighted after the double click (Note that in my application, the highlight is removed if the double click was successful), then refresh the page and try the double click again. This should reduce even more failures in Firefox. But IE 100% failure rate still remains

Comment: @MikeJohnston Nothing that I've found. I even tried fixing it in the IE driver source and building a custom version of the driver, but unfortunately the attempts failed. We were trying to fix a slightly different issue with modifier keys in keyboard interactions, but our attempt went as far as correctly toggling the modifier keys and then not toggling them back again :S We actually don't execute against the IE driver on a nightly basis and we only execute a subset of the test because of these issues.